# Xcode 7 - Build script not generating framework

Tags: frameworks, xcode7

I am trying to generate a .framework on Xcode 7 and always get an error -

Details:  Scheme  was asked to build and archive, but the run destination  is not a deployment platform and this action shouldn't have been allowed.
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project UnitedSDK with scheme UnitedSDK.
    Reason: You cannot archive for the iOS Simulator platform.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 70

Tried to change Targets, but nothing helps. This used to properly work on Xcode 6.